# what is path.theme in bolt CMS and where is it defined?

Tags: bolt-cms

I was just going through the code of _master.twig in the default theme in bolt and i came across the following lines of code:

```
{% set main_width = theme.layout.main_width|default(8) %}
{% set aside_width = theme.layout.aside_width|default(4) %}
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="{{ htmllang() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {# make sure we always display a proper title: The record's title if there is one, appended with the
           sitename. If there is no title, we append the sitename with the payoff, if there is one. #}
        <title>
            {%- if record.title is defined %}{{ record.title|striptags }} | {% endif -%}
                {{ app.config.get('general/sitename') -}}
            {% if record.title is not defined and app.config.get('general/payoff') %} | {{ app.config.get('general/payoff') }}{% endif -%}
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ paths.theme }}css/foundation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ paths.theme }}css/theme.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        {% block headincludes %}
        {% endblock headincludes %}
    </head>
```

I just wanted to know what is `paths.theme` and where is it defined ?? And what does this variable mean in bolt CMS ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, yes. That actually goes back to Bolt 1.x functionality that we were going to remove in 3.x but … time pressures. ;-)

We've recently [removed/cleaned that up in those base templates](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/3.3/theme/base-2016/partials/_master.twig) as we've been implementing the functionality via Symfony Asset for a while.

The correct approach now looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/foundation.css', 'theme') }}">
```

Where `theme` is the Symfony Asset "theme packages", in this case the current running theme, and `css/foundation.css` is the path to `foundation.css`, relative also to the running theme's directory.

As for where are they defined … the [asset service provider](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/3.3/src/Provider/AssetServiceProvider.php).

Comment: hmmmm i am guessing `href="{{ asset('css/foundation.css', 'theme') }}"` assets in the previous line of code adds the actual path !

Comment: In Symfony Asset (the component that powers this functionality), the `theme` represents `Packages` in the location that has the name tag `theme` which in this case is the currently enabled theme.

The `Packages` in `theme` know their relative URL (configured in the service provider), so that relative base would get prepended to the output string, and you'd end up with something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/mytheme/css/foundation.css">` output when the template is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the bolt [Cheatsheet](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/cheatsheet#the-paths-variable). There you find all available paths.

The `paths.theme` variable contains the current relative path to the template root directory, for example `/theme/base-2016/`.

To list all the available path variables in your template just add the following snipped `{{ dump(paths) }}`